# Fonts on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, font

Could someone explain how fonts are readily available for MacBook and iMac, but not for iPhone and iPad?

I'm trying to work with a document (using Pages) that I share on all my devices using iCloud. However the alignments and document size ends up varying largely as my iPad and iPhone do not have Calibri typeface.

Also, there seem to be no easy and straightforward (and free) way to install those fonts on the handheld devices. Can someone point me to one?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+install+fonts+on+ipad&bext=msl&atb=v105-5__&ia=web should get you started

Comment: @patrix: Before asking the question here, I searched using Google and custom searched SO, however (as I said in the last section in the question) there is no easy and sf and _free_ way to install fonts. The DDG search link too takes one to websites that list paid apps for something that's freely and readily available for iMacs and MacBooks. Hence this question.

Comment: Anyfont is the way to go, even if it costs you a buck.

Comment: Alternatively, if you could be more specific about the application you are using there might be other ways.

Comment: I thought it'd be implicit - using Pages/Keynote/Numbers.

Comment: For free, you could use Apple Configurator (from the App Store) to create a profile with fonts and install this on your iDevice